# Clover XML Report - Classes and Trait coverage formula

Tags: php, xml, phpunit, code-coverage, clover

I am working on a customized application to parse through the `clover.xml` report.
Just wondering if anybody knows which is the correct formula to get the `Classes and Traits` total coverage percentage.

Here's the formulas that I found for `Lines` and `Functions&Methods` coverage:

```
// TPC = (coveredconditionals + coveredstatements + coveredmethods) / (conditionals + statements + methods)
phpMetric.project = (((phpMetric.coveredconditionals + phpMetric.coveredstatements + phpMetric.coveredmethods) / (phpMetric.conditionals + phpMetric.statements + phpMetric.methods))) * 100;
// Lines coverage formula - LTPC = (coveredstatements / statements) * 100
phpMetric.lines =  ((phpMetric.coveredstatements / phpMetric.statements)* 100);
// Functions and Methods coverage formula - FMTPC = (coveredmethods / methods) * 100
phpMetric.functions =  ((phpMetric.coveredmethods / phpMetric.methods)* 100);
```

And this is the `metrics` from clover.xml

```
<metrics files="10070" loc="1354443" ncloc="1110810" classes="8575" methods="46082" coveredmethods="31707" conditionals="0" coveredconditionals="0" statements="561696" coveredstatements="371009" elements="607778" coveredelements="402716"/>
```

Update:
The information that I wanna extract from the report is the column `Classes and Traits`, the total coverage %.
[image: Total Coverage Report]

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to extract from the xml?

Comment: @JackFleeting - I'm trying to extract the overall coverage data for each coverage category, such as: Lines Coverage, Functions and Methods Coverage and Classes and Traits. For lines and Functions/Methods, I already got the data from the xml, but for the Classes coverage I didn't.

Comment: I'm afraid it's still unclear, as I have no idea what these things are. Focus on the xml: you have there one element, named `<metrics>` with several attributes (`files`, `loc`, `ncloc`, etc), each of which has an attribute value (`10070`, `1354443` and `1110810`, respectively, etc.). Which of these **specifically** do you need to extract in order to create the report?

Comment: Yes, this is I'm looking for. For example: In the element `metrics` we have the information for methods: `methods="46117" coveredmethods="31733"` - How I can extract the total coverage percentage: `TCP = (coveredmethods / methods) * 100` . Unfortunately, I didn't identify the coveredClasses into the element `metrics`. Not sure how to /where is the coveredClasses elements or something else. The element has the value `classes="8579"` but not `coveredClasses`. Thanks @JackFleeting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about clover, but - if I understand you correctly - you can use php (which is tagged in your question) do something like the following. Obviously, you can then modify it as necessary:

```
$cloverstr = <<<SOMEXML
<root>
   <metrics files="10070" loc="1354443" ncloc="1110810" classes="8575" methods="46082" coveredmethods="31707" conditionals="0" coveredconditionals="0" statements="561696" coveredstatements="371009" elements="607778" coveredelements="402716" />
</root>    
SOMEXML;
$xml  = simplexml_load_string ($cloverstr);

$coveredmethods = $xml->xpath("//metrics/@coveredmethods");
$methods = $xml->xpath("//metrics/@methods");

$coveredstatements = $xml->xpath("//metrics/@coveredstatements");
$statements = $xml->xpath("//metrics/@statements");

$coveredelements = $xml->xpath("//metrics/@coveredelements");
$elements = $xml->xpath("//metrics/@elements");

$TCP = ($coveredmethods[0] / $methods[0]) * 100;
$LTPC = ($coveredstatements[0] / $statements[0]) * 100;
$XYZ = ($coveredelements[0] / $elements[0]) * 100;

echo ("TCP: " . $TCP . ' </br> ');
echo ("LTPC: " . $LTPC . ' </br> ');
echo ("XYZ: " . $XYZ);
```

Output:

```
TCP: 68.805607395512 
 LTPC: 66.0515652595 
 XYZ: 66.260377966955
```